How to format child nodes inside text nodes with XSL-FO?
I am trying to print a node that contains text and child nodes, but can't apply format to child nodes.
I have the following xml:
    <text>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <link>text of the printing</link> and typesetting
 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. </text>

I need to display the text in order and format the link. I also want to add a new line at the end of text.
Here is my xsl:
<xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="link"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link">
        <fo:basic-link color="red" text-decoration="underline" external-destination="{whatever}">
            <xsl:value-of select="whatever"/>
        </fo:basic-link>
    </xsl:template>

With this code, i'm printing the links in place but not formated. Then at the end of the text all links are printed accordingly. Also the new line is not being printed.

Try
<xsl:template match="text">
  <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link">
    <fo:basic-link color="red" text-decoration="underline" external-destination="{whatever}">
        <xsl:value-of select="whatever"/>
    </fo:basic-link>
</xsl:template>


It works like this, thank you a lot! " Two questions. apply-templates is applying all the templates related to the content inside text right? And why do we need fo:block here?

xsl:apply-templates without a select is doing an implicit <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/> meaning it processes all child nodes with matching templates (and text nodes have a built-in template to copy them through).

As for the fo:block, I put it in as the usual approach to have a text block that is separated by some vertical spacing from its neighbouring layout blocks. If the <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> alone gives you the layout you want without the fo:block wrapper, then by all means don't use it. But most layout with FO and/or HTML that wants some separation is done with block elements.

The <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> would ordinarily just make an inline space in the formatted output (and an &#10; at the end of an fo:block would ordinarily be dropped).  I suggest that the perceived line breaks in the result are likely because of the fo:block.
